# Python: Hexadecimal string to image conversion?

Tags: python, string, image, hex

I do have a string that must contain graphical data. The string looks like this:

```
0x32 0x3c 0x2e 0x33 0x34 ...
```

How can I convert and / or display this in Python into an image or image file? I already looked for a solution, but most articles provided help for string in other formats which all look different. Most of them look like this:

```
0000D4948445200000124000001150802000000C6BD0FB30000 ...
```

A simple procedure for conversion and save as PNG, JPG or TIF would be great. Displaying the picture in a window using the image library Pillow would be even better.

Thanks in advance! Ulrich

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: Well, nothing to be honest. As I have no experience with image formats... Sorry!

Comment: Your string is translated into characters `2<.34`. This does not look like an image format. They usually start with some signature bytes. Interestingly it is valid Python code.

Comment: Hi Klaus, the string begins with `0xff 0xd8 0xff`. Is this a signature in your eyes?